# How to configure one login page with Multiple landing pages which intercept with different url patterns in spring security 4

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

My requirement is, I have two different landing pages one for user and one for admin. This landing pages has to be appear based on the intercept url pattern which i configure in the spring security xml file. Both the landing page is having a hyperlink to login, when the user click on the login hyperlink of adminLayout.jsp it will load the same login page and when the user click on the login hyperlink of userLayout.jsp it will load the same login page by interacting with the controller for two different url patterns.The url patterns will be /admin and /user.

I stuck here. 
How can i configure two different landing pages(adminLayout) and userLayout) in spring security. this tow landing pages is having the same login form, which i want to configure in the spring security form-login for both the url patterns and tow layouts.Before login only the landing page has to appear and then when the user click on the login hyperlink from two different pages it has to make user of spring security provided login-form functionality.Please help me out on this.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="http" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="http" />   
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
      <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    <!-- Here i want to configure the landing pages based on the intercept url pattern if the pattern is /admin i want to dispaly the adminLayout.
    If the intercept url pattern is /user i want to display the userLayout. Both this Layout pages is having common login page which user will click from this layout pages.
    if want to make use of spring secuiryt for form login..
     -->    
 <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/sslogin"  authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationHandler" 
        authentication-failure-url="/fail2login?error=true"/>
    <logout  logout-success-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />  


<session-management>
<concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/fail2login"  />
</session-management>
</http>
<beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="com.fss.portal.handlers.PortalAccessDeniedHandler">
 <beans:property name="accessDeniedURL" value="403"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationHandler" class="com.fss.portal.handlers.AuthenticationHandler">
</beans:bean> 
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.fss.portal.utility.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
 <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="bcryptEncoder"></beans:property>
</beans:bean> 
 <beans:bean id="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

 <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider  ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try creating a [AuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html) implementation with multiple landing page support.

It could be something like this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

public class MultipleLandingPageEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint
        implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private Map<String, String> landingPages;

    public MultipleLandingPageEntryPoint(String defaultLoginFormUrl, Map<String, String> landingPages) {
         super(defaultLoginFormUrl);
         this.landingPages = landingPages;
    }

    public MultipleLandingPageEntryPoint(String defaultLoginFormUrl) {
        super(defaultLoginFormUrl);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getLandingPages() {
        return landingPages;
    }

    public void setLandingPages(Map<String, String> landingPages) {
        this.landingPages = landingPages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) {
        for(String key : this.landingPages.keySet()){
            RequestMatcher rm = new RegexRequestMatcher(key, null);
            if(rm.matches(request)){
                return this.landingPages.get(key);
            }
        }
        // If not found in the map, return the default landing page through superclass
        return super.determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(request, response, exception);
    }

}
```

Then, in your security config, you must configure it:

```
    <beans:bean id="authenticationMultiEntryPoint" class="com.xxx.yyy.MultipleLandingPageEntryPoint">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/user/landing.htm" />
        <beans:property name="landingPages">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="/user**" value="/user/landing.htm" />
                <beans:entry key="/admin**" value="/admin/landing.htm" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

And use it in your `<security:http>` element:

```
    <security:http pattern="/admin/landing.htm" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/user/landing.htm" security="none" />
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" 
              entry-point-ref="authenticationMultiEntryPoint">
```

If you implement the AuthenticationEntryPoint extending [LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) (which I think it's a good idea) check additional parameters on it.

EDIT: I've just updated the class implementation, did not include the latest version

Comment: How can I configure the login form page, which is a common for both the urls

Comment: created the same way but showing an exception while loading the application saying, Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationMultiEntryPoint' while setting bean property 'authenticationEntryPoint'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationMultiEntryPoint' defined in ServletContext resource  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.util.Map]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

Comment: You are wright, I did not include the latest version of the class. Please have a look at my answer again.

Comment: Still i have the same problem, showing the same error. i think the constructor we are configuring for the Entry Point class from the bean . there it is showing ambiguity

Comment: I've tested it the way it is in my answer now, and It works for me. Just to check, the `authenticationMultiEntryPoint` bean declaration is in the security config `xml`, sure?

Comment: I found the issue, its because of the version problem , i am using spring 4.x and the bean configuration constructor is different in spring security 3 and 4. You can follow this document.http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-web.  Can you please explain me how the flow is going on little confuse with the flow.

Comment: I am also using spring 4 in the project where I tested it, so I don't understand what is happening to you.

Comment: i am using spring security 4.1.3. i changed the bean constructor declaration from there its working fine. i followed the document which i shared you above comment.

Comment: I really don't understand which part of the code was causing any error, since I tested it with `spring-security-4.2.0`.  I guess you are talking about http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-web-luaep, as the entry point I suggested extends it, but I don't see anything to change on the declaration of the entrypoint since I did use `constructor-arg` exactly as it is said in this document.

Answer (score 1):

Create A Custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` like below

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                           javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response,
                           Authentication authentication)
                             throws IOException,
                                    javax.servlet.ServletException {
         if(authentication.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
              request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin").forward(request, response);
         } else if (authentication.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")) {
              request.getRequestDispatcher("/user").forward(request, response);
         }
    }

}
```

And configure it with `form-login` tag as following

```
<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" ...>
```

**UPDATE**

Create a Controller mappings `/landing` point to it by `<form-login login-page="/landing" .../>`. This landing should have links to admin and user landing pages. Which can have links or forms to login.

You can remove protection from these landing pages.

```
<http pattern="/landing**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/landing/admin**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/landing/user**" security="none"/>
```

And you can write a Custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` to redirect to correct login page.

Comment: I already have the success handler, but before login only it has to display the layout pages based on the intercept url pattern, not after login.

Comment: How to identify the Role of a User before Login into the System? What you should have is a Single Landing Page with two links to Admin and User landing pages.

Comment: is there any way that i can configure the layout pages based on the intercept url pattern then i will configure the login form in spring security.can we use any filters before it forward the request to the login form or checking the access role in the intercept url, We are going to give two different url to the customer to login . i.e one url for admin landing page other url for user landing page

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure a single landing page for the intercept url pattern and then i will provide two different links for user and admin in the single landing page, how to configure landing page  in the spring security